# Php ignore [quote]some content[/quote] from the row body and print the rest content after[/quote]

Tags: php

I have a database with lot of rows,where the body looks like.

**"[quote author=05simpson link=topic=3.msg3#msg3 date=1487141534]
some content
[/quote]
the rest of body content. "**

Now as you see, the body of the content is in between [quote] and [/quote] ..

I need to have an php command to ignore this to `[quote] some content [/quote]` content and echo the rest of the content alone...

I have used `mb_substr()` and `strip_tags()` but none worked..

Comment: not sure about a SQL solution. Would a PHP solution work for you aswell?

Comment: yes , will do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best performance but it will do the trick:

```
<?php

$content = '[quote author=05simpson link=topic=3.msg3#msg3 date=1487141534] some content [/quote] the rest of body content.';

if (preg_match_all('#\[quote(.*)\](.*)\[/quote\]#Usi', $content, $result)) {
    echo '<quote>' . $result[2][0] . '</quote>' ;   // result[2] will contain the seccond (.*)
    echo str_replace($result[0][0], '', $content);  // replace [quote...till...[/quote] from $content
}
```

The result looks like:

```
<quote> some content </quote> the rest of body content.
```

[You can try here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d12127b6012a07baf9738cef32e6941fc2eedde1) click on "Execute code" at the bottom.

The PHP [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php) will in this case match everything which starts with:

`[quote` - what ever is here untill closing - `]`**this is what you need**`[/quote]`

Comment: No dude, you didn't get it, maybe I couldn't able to explain it properly..   actually, i need only `rest of the body content` only.. out of `[quote author=05simpson link=topic=3.msg3#msg3 date=1487141534] some content [/quote] the rest of body content.` body.. ignoring the rest...

Comment: @GuntamukkalaKavya use only the seccond echo then. [See here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa83a7bb3443a877a08533aaf623f6ab8990d429)

Comment: Yo, i have another doubt. what if my body doesn't have any [quote] block but only plain text. I just checked, it doedn't paste the plain text alone.. how to make it echo plain text if it doesn't have any [quote] blocks..?

Comment: never mind, i just added `else` state ment to it. thanks anyway